# Deselecting a single row in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Is this possible without hacking into the innards of the jqGrid JS?

setSelection( "rowX", false ) doesn't work, and resetSelection() deselects *all* rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation, setSelection

> Toggles a selection of the row with id = rowid; if onselectrow is true (the default) then the event onSelectRow is launched, otherwise it is not.

On the demo page, setSelection is called like

```
jQuery("#list9").jqGrid('setSelection',"13");
```

Does this work? Could you supply us with the constructor otherwise?

Comment: This works.  I didn't realize that the second argument to setSelection only determines if onSelectRow is called.  This will satisfy my needs, but ideally there would be a method for setting a row selection regardless of it's current state.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#list9").jqGrid('setSelection',"-1");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery('#list9').jqGrid('resetSelection',row_id);
```

Please pass the number at `row_id` place.
It is worked for me
**#list9** is your grid id and `row_id` is the id of your row which you may get it through events like `onSelectRow`.